# Failing to inject an angular component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So what I am trying to do here is make an angular component and get it injected to my angular app.
Here is the code for the angular component:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('some.someModule', ['bm.component.templates'])
.directive('somesomeModule', somesomeModule);

somesomeModule.$inject = [];
function somesomeModule() {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        templateUrl : 'components/document_preview/document-preview1.html'
    };
}
})(window.angular);
```

I have an app.js where I inject this new component to app module.

```
 var someApp = angular.module('some.app', [
    'bm.component.templates',
    'some.hello',
    'some.someModule',
])
.config(config)
.run(run);
```

I get this from the console:

[image]
The strange thing is I also have an some.hello angular component with the same sort of code and it is working fine. How to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not declaring your custom module as a dependency of your application module.

Please try the following :

```
 var someApp = angular.module('some.app', [
    'bm.component.templates',
    'some.hello',
    'some.documentPreview',
    'some.someModule'
])
.config(config)
.run(run);
```

**EDIT #1:**

Try wrapping your angular module code in an IFFE as you did with your custom one :

```
(function (angular) {
    var someApp = angular.module('some.app', [
            'bm.component.templates',
            'some.hello',
            'some.documentPreview',
            'some.someModule'
        ])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);
})(window.angular);
```

**EDIT #2:** 
[Here's your code working.](http://jsbin.com/socewepuri/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: I have edited the question. It was a mistake. Thank you

Comment: Updated answer @Pushpendra

Comment: I have it wrapped in an IFFE just like the custom one only

Comment: @Pushpendra Its working for me, I added a jsbin link with your code working.

Comment: I will get back to you after checking this. Thank you!

Comment: Ah! I found the issue, There was only one difference between your code and mine. I had an injector in my custom angular component ---> ['bm.component.templates']. I changed it to [] and it started working.

Comment: Cool! Remember that the the array parameter after the module name declares the module dependencies of that module.